# show popup image during pageload in html

Tags: html

need to show an image during the page load. How could it be possible if need to show on `index.html`. Any help, how can i load the image having cross button on upper side ? Any prepopolated script for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function pop() {
var W1 = window.open('popup.html','Popup1',"toolbar=no,status=no,location=yes, directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=160,height=160");
}
</script>

<body onload="pop()">
```

The above script if the answer of my question. thanks